# Using socket code and changing it to python 3.5.0 and getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' error

Tags: python, sockets

Got code from http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/ and changed it to work in python 3.5. It looks like this:

```
#Socket client example in python

import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print ('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()

print ('Socket Created')

host = 'www.google.com';
port = 80;

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

#Connect to remote server
s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print ('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

#Send some data to remote server
message = ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendall(str(message))
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print ('Send failed')
    sys.exit()

print ('Message send successfully')

#Now receive data
reply = s.recv(4096)

print (reply)
```

and the shell is giving the error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" on line 36 where the code is s.sendall(str(message)). Since I'm trying to get into socket programming for a school project I'm really not sure what the error means and haven't found a good example of how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `socket().sendall` method expects a "bytes-like object", which means a `bytes` object (or a bunch of other types like `memoryview`). You are passing a `str` object, which represents a unicode string, to that method.

To fix this error, you need to encode your message with `message.encode(<encoding>)` or `bytes(message,<encoding>)`.